# How to use options (error=recover) in Rscript

Tags: r, rscript

I have an Rscript I would like to run. It takes a very long time to run (took about 23 hours on a 64gb 32 node cluster). It keeps running into an error at this time. My boss told me to run the script locally on my macbook 4gb ram and use options(error=recover). This would stop the code at the error but allow me to enter R at the point of error and play around? Is that correct?

Anyways, I tried using `Rscript options(error=recover) /path/to/file.R` but I got can error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token "("`. What is the proper syntax? I can't find it online...

Comment: the `options(error=recover)` has to be *inside* your script file, unless you get fancy.

Comment: thanks! and if I just run the Rscript and keep terminal in my background, then in like ~days it'll open into R with all the data.frames that were present right before the error?

Comment: presumably.  If I were you I would test it with a small example that will break in a few minutes (i.e a script that consists of `options(error=recover); x<- 1:10; Sys.sleep(60); stop("break here")`

Comment: Ben, how do I open up the debugging environment after the recover is set into play. Can you look at my new post please?