# Is there a way to continue where source() left off?

Tags: r

I am sourcing a script in R, and modifying errors as they arise but I'd like to continue sourcing at the point where `source()` found the error so I don't have to `source` from the beginning.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642553/how-to-use-options-error-recover-in-rscript

Comment: unfortunately I tried this and it didn't work. I am looking for a function or option that preserves the objects and variables created from the sourced file prior to it finding an error.